# Catching Exceptions thrown by Web2Py Database Abstraction Layer

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

Is there a way to catch exceptions thrown by web2py's DAL?

Let us say that I have the following code:

```
for item in data_dict:
    db.table_name.insert(item)
```

If any of the items failed to insert correctly web2py handles this and does not commit any records to the database and creates a ticket. I want to catch the error thrown by the database and output a custom error message.

Wrapping the insert or the entire for loop in a try/except block inserts the valid records and skips and throws errors on the invalid ones, leaving the database in a state where some records have been inserted and others not at all. This is not the intended behavior.

I hope someone can a give me a pain free solution to output a custom error message. I am using web2py 2.7.4

TIA
nav

Comment: What is the typical reason for an insert failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have the solution you're looking for, straight from the web2py documentation:
http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#commit-and-rollback

Simply catch the error, and issue a rollback.

"
No create, drop, insert, truncate, delete, or update operation is actually committed until you issue the commit command"
commit

```
>>> db.commit()
```

To check it let's insert a new record:

```
>>> db.person.insert(name="Bob")
2
```

and roll back, i.e., ignore all operations since the last commit:

```
>>> db.rollback()
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it did not click until you explained it to me even after reading this exact section several times. :-)